# Sliding AABB collision - getting stuck on edges

Tags: algorithm, geometry, collision, game-physics

I'm working on a 3D tile based game and I'm using AABB collision detection. For every cube that the player is intersecting, I find the axis along which the player is intersecting the cube the least, and push the player out of the cube along that axis.

Depending on the order that the cubes are checked in, this can cause problems when sliding along the edge of multiple cubes. I have created a diagram that should explain the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/raiGo.png

- Arrow #1 is the attempted movement of the player. The other arrows are the collision response.
- In the left diagram, collision is tested against the right cube first, causing the player to be pushed to the left, and then upwards. (**bad**)
- In the right diagram, collision is tested against the left cube first, causing the player to be pushed upwards, at which point the player is no longer intersecting the other cube. (**good**)

Any ideas on what the most efficient way to solve this might be? Or any better ways to handle the collision response?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe check all collisions and note the time (or distance) of the collision.  Apply only the collision that happens soonest.  Optionally continue the process for the remainder of the time-step.

Comment: So if I sorted all the cubes the the player was intersecting with by distance from the player, and then considered one at a time, that might work. I'm thinking it would be best to avoid having to sort things every frame, but I'm not sure it would matter much since the player could only be colliding with up to ?7? blocks at a time. Do you think there's anything to worry about there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A discrete implementation forces you to inject some continuous math in the system, only when required (cubes / directions overlap).

For each cube *c1*, *c2* ... *ci* with which the user cube (*uc*) intersects at the time of the check, you want to find out which cube was "touched" first - there is only one, as in real life. Consider the direction `d` of *uc*, and, taking the amount of *uc* in *ci* (overlapping) find the position of *cu* at the time it "touched" *ci*.

Determine which cube was "touched" first *cj* (the one that required the most rollback on the `d` axis - the sooner in time) and use only this one to calculate the collision reaction.

Not only you'll reach accuracy. but it will help if all cubes are moving, have different speeds etc...

Comment: +1. I did something like this once, though it's a pain to implement and debug. You can run into trouble using this approach when the motion of objects from one frame to the next isn't along a linear line, but otherwise it works really well. You'll need to remember the previous position (and maybe previous velocity) of each object that can move so that you can calculate the position and velocity of the objects at any given time between two frames.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding what you are saying, but I think this answer would also have an issue if the player was trying to walk into a corner of a room. I believe it would be necessary to take more than one block into account. I could perhaps sort all the blocks that the player is colliding with, but I'm not sure if it would be best to avoid having to sort things.

Comment: The wall of the room is to be treated the same way as other cubes - this is a particular (easier) case: you check if the cube is out of the bounds, and, using the same algorithm, determine how much of the cube is out, then you check collisions with other cubes. Again, the first "touched" (another cube or the wall) has to be dealt with collision reaction. Wall is just a particular non-moving and bigger object with which the cube may collide.

Comment: I'm saying that if the player walked into the corner, he would be intersecting 3 cubes (if this was 2D). How would I calculate the appropriate response only using one cube, when the player has to be moved along two axis? I think I would have to sort them by distance and potentially consider each of them. Though I would only need to consider two in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From your diagram, it seems you want the smallest move that minimises the overlap between the player and the cubes.  Each cube with overlap will try to "push" the player in two orthogonal directions.  Can you do something like pick the minimum push of the maximum pushes in each direction?

Comment: I think that would cause issues if the player was walking into a corner. In that case, I need to push the player backwards along 2 axis.

Comment: Okay; thinking in 2D, the push must have a vertical and horizontal component.  Each overlapping cube can impart a push in two directions from {N, S, E, W}.  If there are multiple overlapping cubes, then you need to consider the maximum pushes in the {N, S} and {E, W} directions (anything less will leave overlap, but it may be possible to ignore, say, a NS push because an EW push will do the job).  There are at most eight possibilities.  Can you try all eight in order of magnitude and pick the first that clears the player from the cubes?

Comment: Unfortunately, there would be even more possible sets in 3 dimensions. It would probably be more efficient to just initially sort the blocks based on distance as Tom suggested.

Comment: Well, there are at most 26 possibilities for 3D and the only way you'd have to consider all of them is if somehow every face of the player cube intersects with a game cube.

Answer (score 0):

You might implement a kind of hybrid broad phase when your two (or more) stationary cubes in a row can be combined into one larger rectangle. Test against the larger rectangle first. It will give you the results of your green check mark and be faster than checking each cube anyway. Then, after that, only if you need to, check against the individual cubes.

Comment: I'm trying think how I would apply this to 3 dimensions. If I had a shape like an 'L' that was standing up, I could combine 2 blocks horizontally or vertically. But I think the order I would have to apply the response would depend on the player's position or movement direction.

Answer (score 0):

A collision can push an object on 1 axis only. To determine the axis to push:

```
else   -- not this
elseif -- change to this

if w > h then
    push x
elseif h > w then
    push y
end
```

This works if your tiles are aligned.

Use circles to avoid the stick on unaligned tiles